# The free algebra generated by two noncommuting elements $x$ and $y$.

Tags: ring-theory

Let $F$ be a field and define $R=F\langle x,y| xy\neq yx \rangle$ the free $F$-algebra.

I have been googling the meaning or the structure of the ring $R$ for a while but got nothing. I just want anybody to explain for me what is meant by a free $F$-algebra. What is precisely the ring $R$ and what are the forms of its elements.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have the free monoid on two letters with $<x,y \vert xy \neq yx>$. Elements of this monoid are typically reduced words in $x$ and $y$ and one such word would be $x^2y^{5}xy$. Now take all finite linear combinations of these words with coefficients from $F$ and give it a ring structure by doing addition in the natural way (word-wise) and by applying distributivity and the commutativity of the scalars from $F$ to give it a ring structure. So say $F = \mathbb{R}$ some typical elements of $R$ will be things like $4xyx^2 + \pi y^4xyx + x +\sqrt{2}$ where the identity elements is implied to be after the $\sqrt{2}$ and a $1$ in front of the $x$.

Note that this is just the usual group ring construction with the group being the free group on two letters and the ring being $F$.

Comment: As for what it's useful for, this is the general framework for working with arbitrary non-commuting elements in a ring. Ever worked with two arbitrary matrices over $F$? Then you have been working in $R$.

Comment: Your construction is flawed. $x$ and $y$ should not have multiplicative inverses. If you use the free monoid in place of the free group, however, you’re in good shape.

Comment: @MarkSaving thanks I'll make the changes shortly.

Comment: Excuse me, I have another question that I'm confused about. Wikipedia says that $R$ is a free module over $F$. It's clear that the set of all words in $\lbrace x,y \rbrace$ span $R$. But why is this set linearly independent? Is it independent by convention? @CyclotomicField

Comment: In other words, is it true that whenever $f_1w_1+\ldots+f_nw_n=0$ (where $f_i\in F\, \forall i$ and each $w_i$ is a word) then $f_i=0$ for all $i$?. 
@CyclotomicField

Comment: Yes, they're independent by convention.